# Dealing with a basic Blazor form - Missing directive or assembly reference?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've attempted to create my first Blazor form, which seems to be nearly there. Problem I have is: when creating a private namespace - I think it's called a namespace here:

```
private _ExampleForm _exampleForm = new();
```

> Visual Studio is saying 'Namespace _ExampleForm cannot be found (are
> you missing directive or assembly reference?)

The full code is here, which I'm very nearly copying from official [Blazor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

```
@page "/opportunity"
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging    
   
<EditForm Model="@_exampleForm" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />    
    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="_exampleForm.Name" />    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>
    
@code {    
    private _ExampleForm _exampleForm = new(); //PROBLEM LINE   
    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
    // do something
    }
  }
```

I am using .NET CORE 3.0 with automatic C# version detection in Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi @MattHodson, it is `ExampleModel` instead of `_ExampleForm ` in doc. Did you configure `_ExampleForm ` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure configure `_ExampleForm.cs` in root of project:

[image]

```
namespace BlazorApp1
{
    public class _ExampleForm
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you need **specific the namespace**:

e.g: if model exists in Models folder

```
namespace BlazorApp1.Models
{
    public class _ExampleForm
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

razor file:

```
@using BlazorApp1.Models;   //be sure add namespace

@code {
    private _ExampleForm exampleModel = new();

}
```

Comment: Is C# 9 needed for this? Despite having .NET CORE 3, Visual Studio automatically putting me on C# 8, which makes `new()` error as it's a C# 9 feature.

Comment: If you're using .net core 3, you'll need to explicitly set the language version to 9 in your .csproj file. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#defaults